# Resize HighCharts In iFrame Using jQuery.resize() Fails in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, kendo-ui

I have a set of charts in a dashboard page called as an iFrame. The iFrame is not displayed to the user until a click action occurs. Therefor, the charts are rendered to "invisible" DIVs. Each chart is assigned a DIV location within a KendoUI "pane" that uses `inline-block` or `height: 100%; width: 100%` so that the chart fills all allotted space. The general code looks like:

```
        <div id="top-pane" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <div id="top-content-horizontal" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                <div id="topLeftDiv" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; text-align: center">
                    <div>Sme Text</div>
                    <div id="rangeslider" style="width: 80%;">
                        <input />
                        <input />
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <label for="sizeFilterMin">Minimum Size:</label>
                    <input id="sizeFilterMin" value="29000" style="width: 50px; height: 20px;" />

                    <label for="sizeFilterMax">Max Size:</label>
                    <input id="sizeFilterMax" value="90000" style="width: 50px; height: 20px;" />
                </div>
                <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                        Results of filter:
                        <ol id="occList"style="display: inline-block;"></ol>
                </div>
                <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                    <div id="cht1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="mapPane" runat="server" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
            <div id="horizontalMapPanes" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phMap" runat="server" />
                <div id="chartPane" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                    <div id="cht2" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="graph-pane">
            <div id="horizontal" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
                <div id="cht3" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
                <div id="cht4" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
                <div id="cht5" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have handled this by checking for `$(window).resize()` and calling `myChart.reflow()`. This works fine in Chrome, Safari, etc. The issue comes into play in IE9+. The charts `cht1` and `cht2` fail to render correctly. The `cht1` does render correctly on initial load but when I change my Size filters and the new data is applied the chart appears to be at 600x400 in size when it should only be about 300x150. If I try and resize the window it has no affect. If I again change my Size filters and load another set of data then the chart is the correct size and fill the container pane perfectly.

For `cht2` there is a bigger issue. On initial load the chart fills its container but the chart title, navigation buttons, and legend items are all overlapping and unreadable. If I resize the window the chart fills to correct dimensions but the text overlapping issue is still present. Then, when I trigger the data change the chart then fixes itself and it displays correctly.

In both of these charts when I resize the iFrame popup window when the charts look "good" it behaves properly.

**How can I have IE9+ render the charts correctly on initial load and window resize?**

How I create the chart:

```
        window.assetcht1 = function (seriesData, seriesCat) {
            options0 = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'cht1',
                    type: 'bar',
                    spacingRight: 20,
                    spacingTop: 0,
                    spacingBottom: 15,
                    width: $('#cht1').width()
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'category',
                    categories: seriesCat,
                    labels: {
                        step: 1
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '$' + this.axis.defaultLabelFormatter.call(this);
                        },
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '8px'
                        }
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color};white-space:normal;">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b><br />',
                    shared: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        grouping: false,
                        shadow: false,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Historic Sizes',
                    style: {
                        color: 'grey',
                        fontSize: '11px'
                    },
                    y: 25
                },
                credits: {
                    text: 'Source: Size Survey'
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: seriesData
            };

            optionscht1 = new Highcharts.Chart(options0);
        };
```

The chart is also created with global options set in `Highcharts.themeLight` but these global options are not setting any dimensions or sizes for elements; it is just colors, font, tooltips, etc.

I then create the chart with the following call where `cht1seriesData` and `cht1Categories` are assigned based on the range slider values:

```
assetchtOESWage(cht1seriesData, cht1Categories);
```

To handle the iFrame opening (which is a resize event) and for when user alters size of iFrame I call:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('#cht1').highcharts().reflow();
    $('#cht2').highcharts().reflow();
    $('#cht3').highcharts().reflow();
    $('#cht4').highcharts().reflow();
    $('#cht5').highcharts().reflow();
});
```

This works but in IE9+ it just does not fix the overlapping text. The other 3 charts have no issues on loading, changing data, or resizing of the window.

Comment: For me sounds like a bug to report. Does kendo-ui use kind of shadow DOM or something similar? Hard to say what is the culprit, or kendo-ui vs Highcharts or iFrame IE11 vs Highcharts. If you could create live demo, then I will try to find some workaround. Have you tried to use `setSize()` instead of `reflow()`? I guess you need responsive chart, then after `setSize` set inner option `chart.hasUserSize` to `null`.

Comment: @PawełFus I am trying to set up a live demo but unrelated technical issues are holding me back right now. For now I have just destroyed and then rebuilt the chart on resize events which is brute force and not very clean but works for our internal demo we are running. Once we get to production we want it to be better.

Comment: It looks like KendoUI dataviz and jsFiddle do not play nice so no live view. I am going to look into doing the setSize() option later on today.

Comment: Yeah, sure. In fact, demo is required for bug reporting anyway. You can always can contact with email support and send html page with demo.